# Check firestore field of parent document in firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am seeking for your help!
I have a collection /releases which documents have always two sub collections releases/covers and releases/tracks.

I need firestore rules, which make all of these collections and subcollections readable from all logged in users.

Write and delete should only be possible by the owner of the document. On the parent document in the releases collection I have a field uid which matches the firebase auth uid. Also the uid should not be able to be changed ever. Its written on create of the document and from there the uid should at least never change its value.

What could be a firestore rule for this?

I have already made it for the releases document itself but a soon as it comes to the sub collections of it, there are problems with the access appearing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow read for every document in root collection and also all subcollections, you can use the following:

```
 match /yourCollection/{restOfPath=**} {
   allow read;
  }
```

If you want to be specific:

```
 match /yourColleciton/{docID}/subCollection/{subId} {
  allow read;
 }
```